# loading css by RequireJS with Webpack

Tags: webpack, requirejs

how force webpack to treat this requirejs css loading syntax: 'css!./style'

from AMD requirejs module definition:

```
    define(['./bar3.js', 'css!./style'], function(bar3) {
```

with "style-loader!css-loader!" it works like:

```
    define(['./bar3.js', 'style-loader!css-loader!./style'], function(bar3) {
```

I've a try to resolve it with resolveLoader :

```
    resolveLoader: {
            alias: { 
                "css": "css-loader"
            }
    },
```

but can't find a solution for adding more than one,
something like:

```
"css": ["style-loader!", "css-loader"]
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the answer a similar problem (we are moving from requirejs to webpack, but loading in .css files via css-loader), I found that this was the most efficient, easiest way to make the switch:

```
// 'classic_skin' being the alias of the file loaded
import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ `classic_skin`).then( (ClassicSkin) => {
    // Callback Logic
});
```

Leads up to the idea of dynamic imports

https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234